# How do I pass a list to a Java input stream?

Tags: java, file-io, datainputstream

```
public class parseFiles
{
    public static void main(String... aArgs) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File startingDirectory= new File("CGT");
        List<File> files = FileListing2.getFileListing(startingDirectory);
        for(File file : files )
        {
             System.out.println(file);
        }
    }
    <other methods to supply the file listings, etc.>
}
```

This is where I am right now: This works great, and a list of files with full paths outputs to the console without any problems. Now, I want to take each of the files listed in that output, and read them line by line.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String inputLine;
String desc = "";
String docNo = "";
// 
while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    int testVal=0;
    String delim = ",";
    int stringMax = inputLine.length();
    if(inputLine.startsWith("Description"))
    {desc = inputLine.substring(13,inputLine.length());}
else
    if(inputLine.startsWith("Reference Number"))
    {docNo = inputLine.substring(20,inputLine.length());}
     String outputString = desc+delim+docNo;
    //        
    <write series of output strings to flat file>
    //
}
```

`while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)` keeps kicking back with the following error:

```
FileListing2.java:22: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be
 caught or declared to be thrown
   List<File> files = FileListing2.getFileListing(startingDirectory);
                                              ^
FileListing2.java:30: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be
 caught or declared to be thrown
                       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                                                              ^
FileListing2.java:43: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or
declared to be thrown
                       while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)
                                                      ^
3 errors
```

Comment: @DavidWallace- Like I said, I copied the code from something the I know works. I'm a java I/O newbie, and I seem to recall that if I want to parse a file line-by-line I needed a Data stream rather than File. School me if that's an incorrect assumption. :)

Comment: What are you talking about? This is a compiler error you have posted. It's not an exception! Just listen to the error message and declare the exception on your method.

Comment: That's not an exception but rather a compilation error. You need to either catch or throw the exception. If you don't understand this, please have a look at the [Exception Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(file); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Write

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

Comment: @DavidWallace- a-ha looks good...but now, I'm getting an IO exception at `while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)`. `readLine` is a `BufferedReader` method...do you see anything else syntactically wrong here?

Comment: @dwwilson: you should edit your original post and show your code attempt and your exception text. But if these are plain vanilla text files, then a Reader of some sort should work well.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [IOHelper](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper/blob/master/src/com/kentcdodds/javahelper/helpers/IOHelper.java) from [Java Helper](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper/) on github. There are methods for getting all files in a directory and reading a file to a string.